# MS SQL. Что делает этот скрипт?

Tags: sql, база-данных, sql-server

MS SQL. Имеется таблица Equipment и скрипт изменения таблицы Measure. Что делает этот скрипт?

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Measure]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Measure_Equipment] FOREIGN KEY([id_equipment])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Equipment] ([id_equipment])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Measure] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Measure_Equipment]
GO
```

Comment: добавляет внешний ключ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создается ограничение внешнего ключа с именем `FK_Measure_Equipment` (имя ограничения зачастую начинается с префикса `FK`) на таблицу `Measure`.

В данном примере создается ограничение внешнего ключа `FK_Measure_Equipment`, где столбец `id_equipment` таблицы `Measure` указывает на поле `id_equipment` таблицы `Equipment`.